# Calendario em PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um calendario em php e gostaria de saber duas coisas !

Como fazer para que a data comece a contar de segunda ? (Dia 1 segunda, por exemplo), e como fazer com que os domingos apareçam em vermelho.

Eis o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calendário em PHP</title>
    <?php 
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Estamos em <?php echo date('Y');?></h1>
        <p>Hoje é dia <strong><?php echo date('d / '); ?></strong>
            <?php echo date('m'); ?>
            agora são <?php echo date ('H'); ?>horas e
            <?php echo date('i');?> minutos.</p>

        <?php
            function linha($semana){
                echo "<tr>";
                for ($i = 0; $i <=6; $i++){
                    if(isset($semana[$i])){
                        echo "<td>{$semana[$i]}</td>";
                    } else{
                        echo "<td></td>";
                    }
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            function calendario(){
                $dia = 1;
                $semana = array();

                while($dia <= 31){
                    array_push($semana, $dia);
                    if(count($semana) == 7){
                        linha($semana);
                        $semana = array();
                    }
                    $dia++;
                }
                linha($semana);
            }
        ?>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Dom</th>
                <th>Seg</th>
                <th>Ter</th>
                <th>Qua</th>
                <th>Qui</th>
                <th>Sex</th>
                <th>Sáb</th>
                <?php calendario(); ?>
            </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por partes, para pintar os domingos de vermelho é simples, na sua função linha vc cria um if verificando se o número é o correspondente ao domingo, se for vc coloca uma tag class na sua tr(ex: <tr class="vermelho"> e estiliza com o CSS(ex: .vermelho{ color: red;}).
Já para contar a partir de segunda existem várias formas, sabemos que o comando date() pode retornar números que representam os dias da semana (domingo = 1, segunda =2 e etc), basta que no seu array de dias vc use o for de 1 até n-1 e coloque o índice 0 por último, depois da execução do for, que no caso, representa o domingo.

Answer (score 3):

Experimente:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calendário em PHP</title>
    <?php 
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

        $hoje = getdate(strtotime($_GET['t']));

        $ultimoDia = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,
                                       $hoje['mon'],
                                       $hoje['year']);

        $primeiraSemana = (($hoje['wday'] + 1) -
                          ($hoje['mday'] - ((int)($hoje['mday'] / 6) * 7))) % 7;
        // Alternativa:
        /*$primeiroDiaTimestamp = strtotime(sprintf("%d-%0d-01",
                                                  $hoje['year'],
                                                  $hoje['mon']));
        $primeiraSemana = (int)date('w', $primeiroDiaTimestamp);*/
    ?>

    <style>
        td[data-semana="0"] { color: #ff0000; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Estamos em <?= $hoje['year'] ?></h1>
    <p><?= sprintf('Hoje é dia <strong>%0d / %0d</strong>, agora são %02d horas e %0d minutos.',
                   $hoje['mday'], $hoje['mon'], $hoje['hours'], $hoje['minutes'])
    ?></p>

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Dom</th>
            <th>Seg</th>
            <th>Ter</th>
            <th>Qua</th>
            <th>Qui</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>Sáb</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <?php
        for($semana = 0; $semana < $primeiraSemana; ++$semana) {
            echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }
        for($dia = 1; $dia < $ultimoDia; ++$dia) {
            if( $semana > 6 ) {
                $semana = 0;
                echo '</tr><tr>';
            }

            echo "<td data-semana=\"$semana\">";
            echo "$dia</td>";
            ++$semana;
        }
        for(; $semana < 7; ++$semana) {
            echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }
        ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Coloquei o estilo de CSS no HTML, mas é boa prática colocar noutro ficheiro só para CSS.

Usei a função `cal_days_in_month` para ter o último dia do mês.

Para saber qual era o dia da semana, mostrei duas soluções:

- usando a função `strtotime` para obter o "timestamp" do primeiro dia do mês, que depois pode ser usado na função `date`
- fazendo um cálculo aritmético (suponho que a "performance" é melhor - não invoca duas funções complexas):

  1. conta as semana do mês completas que passaram até ao dia de hoje: `(int)($hoje['mday'] / 6`;
  2. subtrai o dia de hoje pelos dias das semanas completas contadas, dando os dias que sobraram: `$hoje['mday'] - ((int)($hoje['mday'] / 6) * 7)`
  3. subtrai o número do dia da semana mais um (domingo é 0, segunda é 1, ...) pelo resultado anterior: `($hoje['wday'] + 1) - ($hoje['mday'] - ((int)($hoje['mday'] / 6) * 7))`

  Por exemplo, hoje é dia 11 e sábado. Passou apenas uma semana completa (11 / 6 = 1,6...). Uma semana tem 7 dias (1 * 7 = 7). Passaram 4 dias depois dos 7 dias (11 - 7 = 4). Se o primeiro dia da semana fosse domingo, passado uma semana mais quatro dias calharia numa quarta-feira. É preciso puxar os dias para sábado (7 dias): 7 - 4 = 3 (uma quarta-feira).

O resto é fácil:

1. deixa passar os dias que não são mostrados no calendário.
2. mostra os dias do mês indicando o dia da semana no elemento "td"; quando for sábado, termina a linha (assumo que está a usar HTML5, que permite atributos `data-*`).
3. Finalmente, deixa passar os dias que sobram até ao final da semana (sábado).

Comment: Agora só não faz um calendário em PHP em português que não quiser :) +1+

Comment: Atenção que corrigi um erro nos cálculos após testes.

Comment: @PedroAmaralCouto. Testei seu código, porém no mês de 10/2018, ele coloca 30 dias e não 31. Observei que tem essa linha `$hoje = getdate(strtotime($_GET['t']));`. A variável `$_GET['t']`, ela vem de onde? Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

```
function linha($semana){
    $dias = count($semana);
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($i = 1; $i < $dias; $i++){
        if(isset($semana[$i])){
            echo "<td>{$semana[$i]}</td>";
        } else{
            echo "<td></td>";
        }
    }
    echo "<td class="vermelho">{$semana[0]}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";   }
```

Complementando o meu comentário anterior, seria algo assim. 
Não testei o código por ser de simples implementação, caso tenha algo errado vc dá uma ajustada, que é bem simples.

Answer (score -4):

```
<title>Calendario</title>
<!-- Meta Tags -->

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="author" content="thyago assemen oliveira">
<meta name="description" content="MANAUS AMAZONAS">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

```
    <div id="calendar" class="container">

        <?php
        $data_atual = date('Y-m-d'); //aaaa-mm-dd (2000-01-30)
        $dia_atual = date('d'); //dd
        $mes_atual = date('m'); //mm
        $ano_atual = date('Y'); //yyyy
        

        $qtdDiasMesAtual = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mes_atual, $ano_atual); //mostra a quantidade de dias correspondente ao mes e ano inseridos respectivamente nas variaveis..
                                                                                    //ex: 11/2022 = 30 dias.

        $dia_semana_mensal = array(); // cria uma array com a primeira semana

        for ($cria_dia_semana_mensal = 1; $cria_dia_semana_mensal <= $qtdDiasMesAtual; $cria_dia_semana_mensal++) {
            $date = date_create();
            date_date_set($date, $ano_atual, $mes_atual, $cria_dia_semana_mensal);
            $dia_semana_mensal[$cria_dia_semana_mensal] = date_format($date, 'w');
        }

        //esse for acima faz uma verificação para saber em qual dia da semana começa o mês atual.



        $meses_extenso = array();
        $meses_extenso[1] = "Janeiro";
        $meses_extenso[2] = "Fevereiro";
        $meses_extenso[3] = "Março";
        $meses_extenso[4] = "Abril";
        $meses_extenso[5] = "Maio";
        $meses_extenso[6] = "Junho";
        $meses_extenso[7] = "Julho";
        $meses_extenso[8] = "Agosto";
        $meses_extenso[9] = "Setembro";
        $meses_extenso[10] = "Outubro";
        $meses_extenso[11] = "Novembro";
        $meses_extenso[12] = "Dezembro";

        $transforma_mes_atual_em_int = intval($mes_atual);
        $mes_atual_por_extenso = $meses_extenso[$transforma_mes_atual_em_int];

        //atribui a variavel $mes_atua_por_extenso o nome do mês atual em português, que será impresso acima do calendário no front




        //essa funçao foi criada para você selecionar quais dias da semana você irá indisponibilizar
        function verificaIndispDiaSemana($dia_semana_verifica){
            $indisp_dia_semana = array();
            $indisp_dia_semana[0] = true;       //indisponibiliza domingo
            $indisp_dia_semana[1] = false;      //indisponibiliza segunda
            $indisp_dia_semana[2] = false;      //indisponibiliza terça
            $indisp_dia_semana[3] = false;      //indisponibiliza quarta
            $indisp_dia_semana[4] = false;      //indisponibiliza quinta
            $indisp_dia_semana[5] = false;      //indisponibiliza sexta
            $indisp_dia_semana[6] = true;       //indisponibiliza sabado

            if($indisp_dia_semana[$dia_semana_verifica]){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }



        function indispDiasAnteriores($hoje){
            $dia_atual = date('d');
            if($hoje < $dia_atual){
                return true; //caso você defina este retorno como true, ele indisponibiliza no calendário os dias anteriores ao dia atual. 
                             //Caso seja false, ele não restringirá os dias anteriores ao dia atual
            }else{
                return false;//caso seja false, ele deixa disponivel os dias igual ou posterior ao dia atual.
                             //caso seja true, ele indisponibiliza os dias igual ou posterior ao dia atual.
            }
        }


        ?>

        <table class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="7" class="text-center">


                    <div class="mt-4 p-2 bg-primary text-white rounded">
                        <h1>
                            <?php echo $mes_atual_por_extenso; //imprime no cabeçalho da tabela o mes atual por extenso
                            ?>
                        </h1>

                    </div>


                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="text-center">
                <th>Dom</th>
                <th>Seg</th>
                <th>Ter</th>
                <th>Qua</th>
                <th>Qui</th>
                <th>Sex</th>
                <th>Sáb</th>
            </tr>

            <?php


            if ($dia_semana_mensal[1] >= 5 && $qtdDiasMesAtual > 30) { // se o dia 1 for numa sexta feira ou sabado e a quantidade de dias do mes for maior que 30

                $semanas_mensal = 5; // ele define que o mes tem 6 semanas

            } else { //se nao

                $semanas_mensal = 4; //ele define que o mes tem 5 semanas

            }


            $cont_dia = 1; // variavel que será incrementada conforme os dias forem sendo impresso. tendo limite até a quantidade de dias que o mês possui



            for ($semana = 0; $semana <= $semanas_mensal; $semana++) { //ao voce ver o calendário do windows. verá que ele possui 5 linhas, entao erá criada 5 linhas e a primeira semana se torna a $semana == 0

                echo "<tr>"; // cria uma linha na tabela

                if ($semana == 0) { //se a semana for == 0 faz referencia a uma verificação da primeira semana

                    for ($dia_semana = 0; $dia_semana <= 6; $dia_semana++) { //dia semana faz referencia aos 7 dias que a semana possui, seguindo a regra do php, que começa domingo com o valor 0 e termina com o sabado com o valor 6

                        if ($dia_semana < $dia_semana_mensal[1]) { //$dia_semana_mensal[1] faz referencia a que dia da semana é o dia 1 do mês atual. entao fiz uma verificação se o dia da semana do for for menor que o dia 1 do mÊs ele imprime espaço vazio

                            echo "<td><button type='button' disabled class='w-100 btn btn-outline-light text-dark btn-block'>&nbsp;</button></td>";
                        } else { //caso o dia da primeira semana for igual ao dia da semana do dia 1 do mes atual ele: imprime o dia 1 e começa a incrementar os dias da primeira semana

                            if (verificaIndispDiaSemana($dia_semana) || indispDiasAnteriores($cont_dia)) { // verifica se a dia da semana é domingo ou sabado ou dia anterior ao dia atual e deixa estas datas indisponiveis para a seleção

                                echo "<td><button type='button'  disabled class='w-100 btn btn-outline-light text-dark btn-block'>$cont_dia</button></td>";
                            } else { //caso não ele deixa disponivel para seleção

                                if ($dia_atual == $cont_dia) {

                                    echo "<td><button type='button' class='w-100 btn btn-primary btn-block'>$cont_dia</button></td>";
                                } else {

                                    echo "<td><button type='button' class='w-100 btn btn-outline-light text-dark btn-block'>$cont_dia</button></td>";
                                }
                            }
                            $cont_dia++; // incrementbtn-lighto de dias17px
                        }
                    }
                } else { // aqui imprime o restante das semanas

                    for ($dia_semana = 0; $dia_semana <= 6; $dia_semana++) { // for criado para percorrer a semana, fazer verificaçõe e imprimir data

                        if ($semana == $semanas_mensal && $cont_dia == $qtdDiasMesAtual) { //verifica se a semana é a ultima semana do mês, lembrando que semana começa com 0 logo semana 4 é a quinta semana

                            if (verificaIndispDiaSemana($dia_semana) || indispDiasAnteriores($cont_dia)) { // verifica se a dia da semana é domingo ou sabado ou dia anterior ao dia atual e deixa estas datas indisponiveis para a seleção

                                echo "<td><button type='button' disabled class='w-100 btn btn-outline-light text-dark btn-block'>$cont_dia</button></td>";
                            } else { //caso não ele deixa disponivel para seleção
                                if ($dia_atual == $cont_dia) {

                                    echo "<td><button type='button' class='w-100 btn btn-primary btn-block'>$cont_dia</button></td>";
                                } else {

                                    echo "<td><button type='button' class='w-100 btn btn-outline-light text-dark btn-block'>$cont_dia</button></td>";
                                }
                            }
                            $cont_dia++; //incremento de dias

                        } elseif ($semana == $semanas_mensal && $cont_dia > $qtdDiasMesAtual) { //verifica se é a semana 4 e se a variavel cont_dia é maior que a quantidade de dias que este mes tem. caso seja verdadeiro, ele começa a imprimir espaços vazio

                            echo "<td><button type='button'  disabled class='w-100 btn btn-outline-light text-dark btn-block'>&nbsp;</button></td>";

                        } else { // se não

                            if (verificaIndispDiaSemana($dia_semana) || indispDiasAnteriores($cont_dia)) { // verifica se a dia da semana é domingo ou sabado ou dia anterior ao dia atual e deixa estas datas indisponiveis para a seleção

                                echo "<td><button type='button' disabled class='w-100 btn btn-outline-light text-dark btn-block'>$cont_dia</button></td>";

                            } else { //caso não ele deixa disponivel para seleção
                                if ($dia_atual == $cont_dia) {

                                    echo "<td><button type='button' class='w-100 btn btn-primary btn-block'>$cont_dia</button></td>";
                                } else {

                                    echo "<td><button type='button' class='w-100 btn btn-outline-light text-dark btn-block'>$cont_dia</button></td>";
                                }
                            }
                            $cont_dia++; //incremento de dias
                        }
                    }
                }
                echo "</tr>"; //fecha alinha na tabela
            }

            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
```